# Play 2.5.6 application on Tomcat or any alternative?

Tags: scala, tomcat, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have created an application on Play framework 2.5.6. I am trying to find out what is the best way to deploy the application on production. I have tomcat installed on my Ubuntu machine. How to create war file and How to deploy on tomcat? I am using Scala Eclipse IDE for development.

Comment: See [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/deployment#appservers).

Comment: But this seems to be for Play 1.1. Also,  it is mentioned that using play command is traditional way in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look [at this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777267/activator-play-framework-with-google-app-engine/38833436#38833436) which is very similar to what you're asking here (albeit directed at GAE).

In a nutshell, the disadvantages of deploying your app to Tomcat are:-

- you have extra work to do to package your application as a WAR
- extra work to deploy it
- your application may not be fully asynchronous running in Tomcat

As that outdated documentation suggests - the simplest way of deploying your app in production is just using the version of [Netty](http://netty.io/) which is packaged as part of a Play application. See the relevant version of [the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying) to create a distribution. You only need a relevant version of a JVM on your prod server in this case.

The flow is generally:-

1. Run `$ dist` to build the binary (this is a zip by default, but you can also [build a tar](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying#The-Native-Packager) if you prefer using `$ universal:packageZipTarball` instead of `dist`).
2. Move it into your Linux production environment
3. Unpack it
4. Set permissions if you build a zip `$ chmod +x /path/to/bin/<project-name>` (not required if you created the tar)
5. Run the app start script (created by the `dist` task) eg. `$ target/universal/stage/bin/<project-name>`

Comment: This looks good. I just tried with a stand-alone deployment. Thanks for the prompt response. So I forget Tomcat now and going ahead with "dist" approach.

Comment: Best way to go. ;)